# Verify new List<String> in text file

Tags: java

***** UPDATED CODE *****

I'm trying to validate if a contact exists in a text file called contacts.txt against when someone types in a new contact, so to avoid duplicates.

I forgot the Path contactsPath when I first posted this question. As @GhostCat pointed out the .contains() DOES not read. So by placing the string of text into a List I'm able to accomplish this.

HOWEVER. My updated error is as such below my code. When I add a new contact. If an existing contact exists it checks for this condition and if the user inputs yes to override then that same contact is re-written.

The output of me trying to add 'Fred Flintstone | 123-123-3333 does not re-write the original contact.

```
public static String addressBook = "contactList";
public static String contacts = "contacts.txt";

public static String addContact() throws IOException {
    Path contactsPath = Paths.get(addressBook, contacts);
    List<String> people = Files.readAllLines(contactsPath);

    System.out.println("Add a new contact");
    System.out.println("Enter Contacts Name");
    String nameInput = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Contacts Number");
    String phoneNumInput = in.nextLine();
    List<String> newContact = Arrays.asList(nameInput + " | " + phoneNumInput);

    for(String person: people){
        if(person.contains(nameInput)){
            System.out.println("There's already a contact named "+nameInput+". Do you want to overwrite it? (Yes/No)");
            String yesNoInput = in.nextLine();
            if(yesNoInput.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || yesNoInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
                Files.write(
                  Paths.get(addressBook, contacts),
                        newContact,
                        StandardOpenOption.APPEND
                );
                continueMenu();
            }
            continueMenu();
        }
    }
    return nameInput;
}
```

**CONTACTS IN THE CONTACTS.TXT FILE**

```
John Smith | 1231234567
Betty Rubble | 444-333-2222
Fred Flintstone | 123-123-4444Fred Flintstone | 123-123-3333
```

Comment: What is variable "contacts" set to?

Comment: Post whatever you are getting in console, and what inputs you are giving.

Comment: @SripriyaV Paths.get(Directory, filename) . So public static String addressBook = "contactList";
    public static String contacts = "contacts.txt";

Comment: Where do you actually read in the list of contacts?

Comment: Where is `contacts` defined?  Does this code even compile?

Comment: @cpt-crunchy, since you are checking if a contact exists using: if(newContact.contains(contacts)), contacts should be the value you need to check for. String contacts = "contacts.txt" will not work!

Comment: @SripriyaV I was thinking that Perhaps I need to check the nameInput against the String contacts = "contacts.txt"?

Comment: This is the documentation I'm going over to help me out. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html

Comment: As said: you *assumed* what cintains() is doing. That is the wrong approach. When you write source code you better understand each and any character that you write down.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

1. Read all contacts, phone numbers from file and put it in List contacts
2. User input to be set in variable to be checked against the list (you are calling this newContact)
3. Check should be:

   if(contacts.contains(newContact))
4. Ensure that the format of string contents in list matches the string formed with the user inputs (name|phone).

EDIT, Something like:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

public static String addContact() throws IOException
{
    Path contactsPath = Paths.get(addressBook, contacts);
    List<String> people = Files.readAllLines(contactsPath);

    System.out.println("Add a new contact");
    System.out.println("Enter Contacts Name");
    String nameInput = in.nextLine(); //Define in to read user input
    System.out.println("Enter Contacts Number");
    String phoneNumInput =  in.nextLine();
    String newContact = nameInput + " | " + phoneNumInput;

    if (people.contains(newContact))
    {
        System.out.println("There's already a contact named "+nameInput+". Do you want to overwrite it? (Yes/No)");
        String yesNoInput = in.nextLine();
        if(yesNoInput.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || yesNoInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
            Files.write(
              Paths.get(addressBook, contacts),
                    newContact,
                    StandardOpenOption.APPEND
            );
            continueMenu();
        }
        continueMenu();
    }           


    return nameInput;
}
```

Also, as pointed out in one of the comments, it is recommended to use a user defined object instead of using | delimiter.

Comment: Just as an FYI. If i output newContact to the console I get.` [Fred Flintstone | 123-123-333]`

Comment: newContact should be a String not a list.

Comment: You should mention to first create a user class that wraps around the various properties of a user.

Comment: I'm actually missing 3 items to this puzzle. ` Path path = Paths.get(addressBook, contacts);  List<String> people = Files.readAllLines(path); ` Then using a for loop to iterate through the people Array. So that I can match that against the nameInput.

Comment: Please refer javadocs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html

And you don't need to iterate through the list, use contains method:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains-java.lang.Object-